If electron is in two places at same time, is its gravitational pull also at two positions at same time?
If electron is in two places at same time, is its gravitational pull also at two positions at same time?
Have experiments been done to investigate this question?

This question is similar to: Can an electron be in two places at the same time?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Consider an electron in a Hydrogen atom.  We do not treat it as being in two places at once.  Why would gravitational interactions be different ?

I've edited your question to emphasize the gravitational aspect of the question, which I think is a valid & interesting one.

Can an electron be in two places at the same time? doesn't answer this question. It says that the wave/particle duality isn't the right way to think about electrons. You should use QFT instead. So using either QM or QFT, would an electron be a spread out source of gravity? Or better, a spread out source of electromagnetic field?

This question is similar to: Is particle superposition reflected in the particle's gravitational footprint?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Could one just put a Dirac electron wavefunction in GR space and see what curves? What are the obstacles?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/814235/what-would-one-use-a-theory-of-quantum-gravity-for/814255#814255

An electron is never in two places at the same time. That's just an unfortunate mental model that has established itself in the public's imagination about quantum mechanics. In reality superposition is a mathematical property of the theory. It is not a physical property of quantum systems.

@FlatterMann "An electron is never in two places at the same time" Why physicist teach us that is in two places in same time? So Einstein was right, no mystery in physics?

There are, undoubtedly, a lot of poor explanations of quantum mechanics out there. That electrons are things that can be in two places at the same time is one of them. An electron is a small amount of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge that gets exchanged between two system. That alone rules out that it is in any place at all. A system is not a localized physical object.

@FlatterMann But electron has mass,it is real, so must be somewhere?

Mass is a system property, just like energy, so no. Just because we measure the rest mass of a system doesn't mean that it must be exactly in one point.

@FlatterMann Is nature deterministic or random?

Neither. The deterministic/random pair is a false dichotomy fallacy from a time (17th to 19th centuries) when people didn't understand the implications of these assumptions well enough. It is not helpful if you want to understand quantum mechanics. In quantum mechanics we are dealing with independent ensembles of experiments. The independence does not allow for determinism but it does not automatically lead to randomness, either. Instead there is a curious third possibility and that is quantum mechanics.
