Why doesn't gravity cause wavefunction collapse?
Let's take the double-slit experiment for example, the stream of particles shot through the slits show different patterns on the detector depending on whether the particles have been observed to pass through a particular slit. In my intuition, which may or may not be wrong, I have always considered observation to be any sort of interaction with a particle that leads to a wavefunction collapse. Isn't gravity in constant interaction with anything possessing energy? Shouldn't this "measurement" by the gravitational force of a particles momentum, etc. lead to wavefunction collapse?

This question is similar to: Why doesn't gravity act as a measurement?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In the time that has since passed from when Lubos gave that answer, it has only gotten worse. We have way heavier and stronger macroscopic systems that can still be put into superpositions, i.e. if there are any gravitational or spontaneous wavefunction collapses, then those ideas are now in direct contradiction with experiment. You cannot simultaneously have strong enough interaction to cause collapse for smaller systems at the rates we know exist, and also have weak enough interaction to avoid collapse for those bigger systems that we prevented collapse thereof.

Some relevant answers
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/814235/
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/741862/

If gravity is not a quantum force, you would not expect it to cause wave function collapse anyway.
